# Avoid `useEffect` from fetching data on mount when dependency requires user input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React hook `useEffect` runs when a component mounts. However, if the effect has a dependency on user input, the on mount execution of the effect - is redundant. Is it then acceptable to run validations on the dependency and then execute the hook accordingly?

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sea-or6qs?fontsize=14)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDogImage = async () => {
        const dogImage = await axios
            .get(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
            .then(response => response.data.message);

        setDogImage(dogImage);
    };

    // This avoids fetching dog image on mount - user hasn't searched for a dog breed, yet.
    // Is this an acceptable pattern?
    if (breed !== '') {
        fetchDogImage();
    }
}, [breed]);
```

Comment: any reason why you suspect it might not be acceptable? it sounds obvious to me that some code is executed only if some conditions are met => not sure what could make you think it unacceptable, to provide a better rule of thumb how to write code... but in general, `If you imagine yourself reading the code 6 months from now, will you understand it?` might be a good start about what is "acceptable" ;)

Comment: This is acceptable!

Comment: Just wondering if there was an alternative/ this approach had any pitfalls. It seems to be a valid pattern for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think it's okay to check to prevent the run for first time. In addition, you can [useDebouce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce) to prevent too frequent for your search too. For example

```
function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value);
      }, delay);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    },
    [value, delay],
  );

  return debouncedValue;
}

function App() {
    const [dogImage, setDogImage] = useState('');
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState('');
    const debouncedValue = useDebounce(breed, 1000);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDogImage = async () => {
            const dogImage = await axios
                .get(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${debouncedValue}/images/random`)
                .then(response => response.data.message);

            setDogImage(dogImage);
        };

        if (debouncedValue !== '') {
            fetchDogImage();
        }
    }, [debouncedValue]);

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```